# Editing the labels and position of the axis ticks on a seaborn heatmap results in an empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a seaborn heatmap with custom locations and labels on both axes. The dataframe looks like this:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoWyN.png)

I can plot this normally with `seaborn.heatmap`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.heatmap(genome_freq.applymap(lambda x: np.log10(x+1)),
            ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[Normal heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qghi1.png)

I have a list of positions I'd like to set as the xticks (`binned_chrom_genome_pos`):

```
[1000000, 248000000, 491000000, 690000000, 881000000, 1062000000, 1233000000, 1392000000, 1538000000, 1679000000, 1814000000, 1948000000, 2081000000, 2195000000, 2301000000, 2402000000, 2490000000, 2569000000, 2645000000, 2709000000, 2772000000, 2819000000, 2868000000, 3023000000]
```

However, when I try to modify the xticks, the plot becomes empty:

```
plt.xticks(binned_chrom_genome_pos)
```

[Modified heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjpie.png)

I also noticed that the x-axis labels do not correspond to the ticks specified.

Could someone assist me in plotting this properly?

Comment: Can you try `ax.set_xticks(binned_chrom_genome_pos)`? Also, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This results in the same issue.

Comment: can you try `ax.get_xticks()` to see what is in there before you overwrite it?

Comment: `[5.0000e-01 8.9500e+01 1.7850e+02 2.6750e+02 3.5650e+02 4.4550e+02
 5.3450e+02 6.2350e+02 7.1250e+02 8.0150e+02 8.9050e+02 9.7950e+02
 1.0685e+03 1.1575e+03 1.2465e+03 1.3355e+03 1.4245e+03 1.5135e+03
 1.6025e+03 1.6915e+03 1.7805e+03 1.8695e+03 1.9585e+03 2.0475e+03
 2.1365e+03 2.2255e+03 2.3145e+03 2.4035e+03 2.4925e+03 2.5815e+03
 2.6705e+03 2.7595e+03 2.8485e+03 2.9375e+03 3.0265e+03]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### why the code does what it does

`ax.get_xticks()` returns the positions of the ticks. You can see that they are between 0.5 and 3000. These values refer to the index of your data. Large values, set by `plt.xticks`, or `ax.set_xticks` are still interpreted as data indices. So, if you have 10 rows of data, and set `xticks` to `[0, 1000]`, the data in your figure will only occupy 1% of the x-range, hence disappearing. I am not sure if I am making myself clear, so I will give an example with synthetic data:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#generating data
dic = {a:np.random.randint(0,1000,100) for a in range(0,1000000, 10000)}
genome_freq = pd.DataFrame(dic, index=range(0,1000000, 10000))

#plotting heatmaps
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

sns.heatmap(genome_freq.applymap(lambda x: np.log10(x+1)),
            ax=ax1)

sns.heatmap(genome_freq.applymap(lambda x: np.log10(x+1)),
            ax=ax2)


old_ticks = ax2.get_xticks()
print(np.min(old_ticks), np.max(old_ticks), len(old_ticks)) # prints 0.5 99.5 34

ax2.set_xticks([0,300]) # setting xticks with values way larger than your index squishes your data

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### what can be done to fix it

So, what you want to do, is to change the xticks based on the size of your data, and then overwrite `xticklabels`:

Given the new labels from your question:

```
new_labels = [1000000, 248000000, 491000000, 690000000, 881000000, 1062000000, 1233000000, 1392000000, 1538000000, 1679000000, 1814000000, 1948000000, 2081000000, 2195000000, 2301000000, 2402000000, 2490000000, 2569000000, 2645000000, 2709000000, 2772000000, 2819000000, 2868000000, 3023000000]

len(new_labels) # returns 24

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
sns.heatmap(genome_freq.applymap(lambda x: np.log10(x+1)),
            ax=ax)
```

So, now we want 24 evenly spaced xticks between the former minimum and the former maximum. We can use `np.linspace` to achieve that:

```
old_ticks = ax.get_xticks()
new_ticks = np.linspace(np.min(old_ticks), np.max(old_ticks), len(new_labels))
ax.set_xticks(new_ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I've been looking for